# PHP dividing decimal/integer values gives round up output

Tags: php

When I'm dividing,

```
echo 50.3228679581385 / 100;
Output:0.50322867958139
```

It should be `0.503228679581385` . Is there any way to avoid default round up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I have searched in PHP tags.! can't find it. So posted it.!

Comment: Read the article, it explains all the things about floating point numbers and arithmetic operations on a computer ;-)

Comment: Yep. Definitely...! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an INI setting for that, where 14 is the default value:

> ; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
>   ; http://php.net/precision
>   precision = 14

Increase to 15 or more, as necessary. Also works at runtime like this:

```
ini_set('precision', 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not default round up, it's because of the precision limit on double.

Comment: That's ok. To fix this?

Comment: This is a valid answer imo but it lacks references and explanation.